# Elasticsearch filtering by part of date

Tags: elasticsearch

**QUESTION** Maybe anyone has solution how to filter/query ElasticSearch data by month or day ? Let's say I need to get all users who celebrating birthdays today.

mapping

```
mappings:
    dob: { type: date, format: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSS"}
```

and stored in this way:

```
 dob: 1950-06-03T00:00:00Z
```

main problem is how to search users by month and day only. Ignore the year, because birthday is annually as we know.

---

**SOLUTION**
I found solution to query birthdays with wildcards. As we know if we want use wildcards, the mapping of field must be a string, so I used *multi field* mapping.

```
mappings:
    dob:
        type: multi_field
        fields:
            dob: { type: date, format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'}
            string: { type: string, index: not_analyzed }
```

and query to get users by **only month and day** is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "dob.string": "*-06-03*"
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**
This query can be slow, as it needs to iterate over many terms.

**CONCLUSION**
*It's not pretty nice way, but it's the only one I've found and it works!.*

Comment: Can you please provide details in which format you store date field in elasticsearch index ? . It will be good if you share what you are trying and what is your expected output.

Comment: Another solution would be to simply store the month and day as not_analyzed string, and check todays month-day against that field. No need for slow wildcards then.

Answer (score 2):

You should store the value-to-be-searched in Elasticsearch. The string/wildcard solution is half the way, but storing the numbers would be even better (and faster):

```
mappings:
    dob:
        type: date, format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
    dob_day:
        type: byte
    dob_month:
        type: byte
```

Example:

```
dob: 1950-03-06
dob_day: 06
dob_month: 03
```

Filtering (or querying) for plain numbers is easy: Match on both fields.

```
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "dob_day": 06,
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "dob_month": 03,
              }
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

PS: While thinking about the solution: Storing the date as self-merged number like "06-03" -> "603" or "6.03" would be less obvious, but allow range queries to be used. But remember that 531 (05-31) plus one day would be 601 (06-01).

A manually-computed julian date might also be handy, but the calculation must always assume 29 days for February and the range query would have a chance of being off-by-1 if the range includes the 29st of Feb.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I am assuming that you want a query, and not a filter (they are different), you can use the date math/format combined with a range query.

See: [range query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) for usage

For explanation of date math see the following [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#date-math)

`curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search -d`

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
        "birthday": {
            "gte" : "2014-01-01",
            "lte" : "2014-01-01"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tested this with the latest elastic search.

Comment: Doesn't work: The question asked how to select users which celebrate their birthday today, but the stored value is the date of birth (e.g. 1980-05-20 and 1990-05-20 should match when searching for 05-20).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to parse strings, you can use a simple script.  This filter will match when dateField has a specific month in any year:

```
"filter": {
    "script": {
        "lang":   "expression",
        "script": "doc['dateField'].getMonth() == month",
        "params": {
            "month": 05,
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the month parameter is 0-indexed.

The same method will work for day of month or any other date component.