# Elasticsearch - Incoming birthdays

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I'm new with elasticsearch and I'm stuck with a query.

I want to get the next (now+3d) birthdays among my users. It looks simple but it's not because i have only the birthdate of my users.

How I can compare only months and day directly in the query when I only have a birthdate (Eg: 1984-04-15 or 2015-04-15 sometimes) ?

My field mapping:

```
"birthdate": {
    "format": "dateOptionalTime",
    "type": "date"
}
```

My actual query that doesn't work at all:

```
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "birthdate": {
            "format": "dd-MM",
            "gte": "now",
            "lte": "now+3d"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I saw this post [Elasticsearch filtering by part of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010876/elasticsearch-filtering-by-part-of-date) but I'm not a big fan of the solution, and I would prefer instead of a wilcard a "now+3d"

Maybe I can do do something with a script ?

Answer (score 0):

"Format" field was added in 1.5.0 version of elasticsearch. If your 
version is below 1.5.0 format will not work. We had a same problem where we had to send an email on user's birthday and we were using version 1.4.4. So we created a separate dob field where we stored date in "dd-MM" format.

We changed the mapping of date field:

```
PUT /user
{
  "mappings": {
   "user": {
     "properties": {
      "dob": {
       "type": "date",
       "format": "dd-MM"
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Then you can search:

```
 GET /user/_search
 {
   "query": {
    "filtered": {
     "filter": {
      "range": {
        "date": {
          "from": "01-01",
          "to": "01-01",
          "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```