# Elasticsearch Filtering part of date ignoring Year like SQL DATEPART function

Tags: elasticsearch

The problem is similar to [Elasticsearch filtering by part of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010876/elasticsearch-filtering-by-part-of-date)

I have a document having one field mapping is like :

```
"ActivityDate": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "ignore_malformed": true,
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
               }
```

I am trying to get all ActivityDate that happened on 9th of December, irrespective of years.
I am trying various way of script filter like :

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "script":{
          "script":" doc['ActivityDate'].value.getMonth() == 12" ,
          "lang":"expression"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @CalebKleveter, thanks for doing the formatting. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you need to do it like this:

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "script":{
          "script": "doc.ActivityDate.date.getMonthOfYear() == 12 && doc.ActivityDate.date.getDayOfMonth() == 9"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on our discussion in comments, the only thing I can think of is because of the `ignore_malformed` property being true. Some dates probably don't satisfy the pattern you've configured and are thus not `Date` objects but `String` ones. That's the only thing that would explain the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it is not working and also I didn't find any documentation for this type of call 'doc.ActivityDate.date.getMonthOfYear() ' Also the solution you provided doesn't include any "lang" attribute which means it default to "lang":"groovy" and I didnt find any groovy method call like that. I would be happy if you give me some links to get this working.

Comment: Weird, I've tested on my own indices and it worked out well. You're right that if lang is not specified, groovy is the default. `doc.ActivityDate.date` is a [Joda `DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object, hence you can benefit from all the methods of that API.

Comment: When you say "it is not working", what do you get/see? Any errors?

Comment: I am calling 'doc.c_datecreated.date.getMonthOfYear() == 12) and getting this exception in sense: ''{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; Exception evaluating property 'date' for org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Strings, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: date for }

Comment: Hi @Val, Are you using some another language plug-ins that support this doc.FieldName.date.SomeFunctionCall()  ? I think elasticsearch internally stores Date type as LONG.

Comment: No plugin, I'm simply leveraging groovy which is built-in. <thinking />

Comment: them I am not sure why I am getting these exceptions.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is because of the `ignore_malformed` property, where some dates don't satisfy the pattern you've configured and are thus not `Date` objects but `String` ones. That's the only thing that explains the error you're getting.

Comment: your answer solved my problem on new index/document I created it wasn't working on my older index, may be some ill formatted date. Thanks for your help. I am not sure how to mark your answer as complete.

Comment: Nice!! I've updated my answer based on our discussion. You may just click the checkmark to the left ;-)